# r shiny print query result in console

Tags: r, shiny

I am pulling in a query results in my R shiny app. I want to be able to see the format of the results before i create functions to do what i need for my app. This is the basic setup for my R shiny app

```
#libraries
 library(DBI)
 library(rJava)
 library(RJDBC)

#the driver is a JDBC if that helps
con <- dbConnect(drv, url "some url")
my_query = "select * from my_table"
print(my_query)
server <- function(input, output, session){
}
ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(
))
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This just gives me

```
[1] "select * from my_table"
```

in the console in RStudio

How can i show my query results in the console of R studio for my shiny app?

Comment: You need to execute this query using e.g. `DBI::dbSendQuery`. See a vignette (not sure if you're using DBI or not): https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/vignettes/DBI-1.html

Comment: use `shinyjs::logjs()`

Comment: im using a JDBC and i've included the DBI, rJava, and RJDBC libraries

Comment: You can do something like: `df <- RODBC::sqlQuery(con, my_query)` and then `str(df)`

Comment: @VisheshShrivastav i get an error of sqlquery is not an exported object from 'namespace:RJDBC'

Comment: Since you are using RJDBC and DBI, can you try `df <- dbGetQuery(con, my_query)` and then `str(df)`

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to pass the output from the server to the ui. In the server you should have the code that will fetch the data from query. After that the output is passed to ui.

Try your code in the below format. It is only an indicative example. Please update this code with your original parameters.

```
 library(DBI)
 library(rJava)
 library(RJDBC)

 server <- function(input, output, session){
      con <- dbConnect(drv, url "some url")

      output$table1 <- renderTable({
             my_query = "select * from my_table"
             dbGetQuery(con,my_query)
       })
 }

  ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(
     tableOutput("table1")
  ))

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sumanta's answer is right, however remember to close the connection to the database.

```
df <- dbGetQuery(con,my_query)
on.exit(RJDBC::dbDisconnect(con))
```

To check for format you could use

```
str(df) # as some people have mentioned above
# or 
glimpse(df)
```